# Calculating curvature, which 'formula'?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I'm using do Carmo's book of Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces. The literature tells us that the curvature $k(s)$ is defined by 
\begin{equation}
k(s) = |\alpha''(s)|
\end{equation}
However, in one of the exercises (for reference: par 1.5, question 12b), we had the following:

**Question 12** Let $\alpha : I \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular parametrized curve and let $\beta : J \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a reparametrization of $\alpha(I)$ by the arc length $s = s(t)$, measured from $t_0 \in I$. Let $t = t(s)$ be the inverse function of $s$ and set $d\alpha/dt = \alpha'$. Prove that 
\begin{equation}
k(t) = \dfrac{|\alpha' \wedge \alpha''|}{|\alpha'|^3}
\end{equation}

I need to calculate the curvature of
\begin{equation}
\alpha(t) = (t,t^2,t^3)
\end{equation}
The solution tells us that that we need to use the identity
\begin{equation}
k(t) = \dfrac{|\alpha' \wedge \alpha''|}{|\alpha'|^3}
\end{equation}
My question is: why can we not use the first identity? It yields a more, but different, answer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula $k(s)=\lvert\alpha''(s)\rvert$ works for a regular curve $\alpha(s)$ **parametrised by arclength** $s$.  It doesn't work if you parametrise your curve differently, as you discovered.

On the other hand, $k(t)=\dfrac{\lvert\alpha'(t)\times\alpha''(t)\rvert}{\lvert\alpha'(t)\rvert^3}$ works for all regular parametrisation of a space curve.

Comment: Ah, missed that! thanks